# Direct Debit Payments

Tags: cognito-forms

Can Cognito Forms accept debit cards as well as credit cards? Can it accept EFT / bank transfer? If so, how would I go about this?

If not, this is an essential feature.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer on [Cognito Forms](http://www.cognitoforms.com).

Cognito Forms does use Stripe to process payments, so we fully support all of the card types (debit, credit, gift, etc..) supported by the Stripe processor.

Currently we do not support EFT/Bank Transfers transactions.  We have plans to implement this feature in a future release.  However, we do not have a timetable for when it will be release.  You can vote for and follow the progress of the card over on our public [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/oRvjKSHY).

Answer (score 1):

The payments are processed by Stripe. Here’s Stripe’s help article regarding accepted cards:

> With Stripe, you can charge almost any kind of credit or debit card:
>
> - U.S. businesses can accept Visa, MasterCard, American Express, JCB, Discover, and Diners Club.
> - Australian, Canadian, and European businesses can accept Visa, MasterCard, and American Express.
>
> You can also accept gift and prepaid cards that are one of the above types. You can use Stripe to charge cards of these types from customers [anywhere in the world](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-accept-payments-from-customers-who-are-located-in-other-countries). Depending on where your business is located, you can also charge customers in their [local currencies](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-currencies-does-stripe-support).
>
> We’re currently testing Bitcoin support. Join our waiting list for the beta [here](https://stripe.com/bitcoin).

[Source](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-cards-and-payment-types-can-i-accept-with-stripe).